# How does one define a gapless phase of matter?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, phase-transition, topological-order

Often we define a quantum phase of matter as a set of ground states of a gapped family of Hamiltonians, where the gap does not close anywhere in the family. Equivalently, we can define it as a set of states which are related by constant depth quantum circuits with local gates (equivalence of these two definitions is shown by the adiabatic theorem).

Now consider a family of states which are ground states of a gapless family of Hamiltonians, and assume they have similar correlations and can be considered a "phase of matter" in the sense that all their observables vary analytically with the parameters of the Hamiltonian. Can we use the circuit definition of a phase of matter in the same way as the gapped case? That is, is it reasonable to define a "gapless phase of matter" in terms of states which are related to each other by a constant depth-quantum circuit? Maybe there are counter-examples to this which demonstrate this is not true.

In particular, it seems reasonable to define gapless phases of matter in this way as (a) local unitaries do not change long-ranged entanglement properties, which intuitively define phase (b) unlike the Hamiltonian case, we do not need to worry about excitations to higher energy levels.

Is there any literature on this at all?